# CMake: Override libraries added by target_link_libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform, dlib

So I am running into a pretty large headache building my software with CMake.

I am building a third party library statically (dlib) which requires zlib and libpng (both also static, I prebuilt these) libraries to support PNG functionality. The CMakeFile provided by the COTS dlib library is doing a basic:

```
target_link_libraries( dlib ${dlib_required_libs})
```

This is making all of its libraries configured as "general" libraries, which end up being used for both Release and Debug builds.

This isn't an issue in Linux, but Windows has a lovely "feature" of specifying the runtime library (/MT or /MD or /MTd or /MDd). Any mismatches between these flags cause multiple symbol definition errors at link time. i.e. If libpng was built with /MT and my software is using /MTd, they will be incompatible.

To alleviate this, I have two built versions of zlib and libpng. One set using the /MT flag for Release builds and the other /MTd for Debug builds. These happily link into my own software using optimized/debug flags on target_link_libraries where they are used. HOWEVER, dlib (3rd party) is only linking the Release set of the zlib and libpng libs by the way it's CMakeFile has been written.

My main question is, is there a way I can 'override' what dlib is linking without modifying it's provided CMakeFile? 
I attempted overwriting dlib_LIB_DEPENDS and forcing it into the cache out of desperation, to no avail.

Comment: According to [dlib/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/dlib/CMakeLists.txt), `PNG` library is searched via `find_package`, and `zlib` is compiled from sources with the `dlib` project itself. So linking with `zlib` is not a problem: compiled `zlib` takes same compile definitions as `dlib` itself, isn't it?

Comment: Sadly, libpng is dependent on zlib so a precompiled zlib was needed to compile libpng.

Comment: Well, actually, let me correct that. A matching zlib library (with /MT or /MTd) was needed to *link* with the corresponding libpng.

Comment: Hm, as PNG is searched with `find_package`, the simplest way would be to set cache variable `PNG_LIBRARY` to what you need: either `optimized png-lib-release debug png-lib-debug` or `$<$<CONFIG:Release>:png-lib-release>$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:png-lib-debug>`.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds like a nice hacky way of doing it, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @Tsyvarev YOU DID IT! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindPNG.cmake` script, like many other `Find*.cmake` scripts used by `find_package()`, does not care about multiconfig builds. So it just searched *single library*, while multiconfig builds naturally want *library-per-config*.

For make searched PNG library to be per-config, one can to write own `FindPNG.cmake` script (and set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to point to the directory with this script).

But for concrete usage it is simpler to just rewrite output of the original script, that is set `PNG_LIBRARY` cache variable pointed to *library-per-config*:

> optimized *png-lib-release* debug *png-lib-debug*

or, using generator expressions,

> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:*png-lib-release*>$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:*png-lib-debug*>`

(instead of *png-lib-release* and *png-lib-debug* should be paths to the release and debug version of the library conrrespondingly).

Both these values are expected to be used with `target_link_libraries` command,
producing per-config linkage.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer, just in case anyome happens to come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dlib comes with copies of libpng and zlib in dlib/external.  By default, dlib's CMakeLists.txt will build them the correct way and statically link them into your program.  So the solution is to let it do that.  Don't try to create a separate static library because, as you noted, that causes a lot of trouble on windows.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using an older version of dlib which does not come with libpng and zlib with no option for upgrading. Good answer though

Comment: It's been at least two years since dlib has included libpng and zlib in the distribution.  Why not use a newer version?

Comment: Because that is not under my control and the (multiple) programs using it are much older than that.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a pain :)